# Looking for an example on quadtree based LOD terrain

Tags: c++, opengl, terrain, quadtree

I've been searching google and amazon but couldn't find any decent sources on quadtree based LOD terrain. Some just explained the rough concept but this is something I already know what I need is an example with some comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the [LOD page](http://vterrain.org/LOD/Implementations/) at the Virtual Terrain Project.

Answer (score 5):

Ages ago (>10 years) I wrote a quadtree based terrain renderer, that directly reads Terragen-1 files. You need to supply a prerendered surface/illumination texture. The whole thing never was meant to be something serious. The first iteration of the code started as a "keep me from boredom" during a lengthy train trip, within about 6 hours. Then I added to it LOD and some other goodies.

I've put the code as it was on my harddisk on Github, enjoy:

https://github.com/datenwolf/codesamples/tree/master/samples/OpenGL/qt_terr

This thing renders the terrain using immediate mode. Turning this in a vertex array based renderer is left as an exercise to the reader.